# How can I add a alias for field in protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

We have a very old proto messages like this

```protobuf
message SomeProto {
  string original_field = 1;
  //other fields
}
```

But, original_feild's name is misleading because many changes were made during product lifecycle, and now everyone on the team is confused everytime they are using it.

I want to be able to add a alias for field 1, so that it is still compatible with old apps. If it was enum, I could've done something like this.

```protobuf
message SomeProto {
  option allow_alias = true;
  string changed_field = 1;
  string original_field = 1; [deprecated = true;]
  //other fields
}
```

But, of course it doesn't work on message.

Is there a graceful way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to add a alias for field 1, so that it is still compatible with old apps.

Binary compatibility is retained as long as you keep the tag number the same, you are free to change the field name.

To retain source code compatibility, there aren't that many options available.
You could copy the whole message definition as `SomeProtoV2`, but that is probably not very useful in the long term. I would just modify the source code when the .proto file gets updated.

In compiled languages you'll get errors from any line that has not been updated, so it is easy to find. For scripting languages a project-wide search is a good idea.